# How to turn my custom controller into root controller programmatically in SWIFT? (Could not load NIB)

Tags: swift, xcode-storyboard

I dynamically created a XCode project in iOS 14 without StoryBoard. HomeViewController is my custom class. I get this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle with name 'HomeViewController''

Here is my Scene Delegate Class:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: just initialize viewcontroller like `HomeViewController()` and you good to go

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing your View Controller like this:

```swift
window?.rootViewController = HomeViewController(nibName: "HomeViewController", bundle: nil)
```

Initialize it like that:

```swift
window?.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
```

This is because when you specify `nibName` iOS thinks you are trying to initialize from Storyboard or somewhere else.

finished code:

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        window?.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```